# facing json decode error even on a hard coded small dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

facing json decode error, on a dictionary written in python and also on external json files.

```
import json

x = '{ "name:"John", "age":30, "city":"New york"}'
y = json.loads(x)
print(y ["age"])

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 10 (char 9)
```

Comment: : should be after the " symbol (name key)

Comment: Take a closer look at the 9th character of the input string: is this quote supposed to be there?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your string `x`, you forgot a `"` there.

```py
import json

wrong_x = '{ "name:"John", "age":30, "city":"New york"}'
good_x  = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New york"}'

y = json.loads(good_x)
```

This will work. If the stringified dictionary x is hardcoded beyond your control then you will have to write a fix-function for that.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid error from my side, but facing the same issue on a json file. Sample json file  -                                                                                        [
    {
        "ï»¿Sr. No.": "1",
        "Symbol": "ADANIPORTS",
        "ISIN": "INE742F01042",
        "Security Name": "Adani Ports and Special Economic Zone Limited",
        "Overall Permitted Qty. Across All Segments": "148033049",
        "Memberwise Permitted Qty": "N.A",
        "Minimum Haircut %": "VAR rate"
    } ]    ,, i have tried using delimiter, decoding argument in json.loads function

Comment: And the error you get is the same? The first element of your json list (`"ï»¿Sr. No."`) hints on an encoding problem. But it would really help to get the real error on the real data.

Comment: fixed "ï»¿Sr, the first element of json is  -- [
  {
    "Sr. No.": 1,
    "Symbol": "ADANIPORTS",
    "ISIN": "INE742F01042",
    "Security Name": "Adani Ports and Special Economic Zone Limited",
    "Overall Permitted Qty. Across All Segments": 148033049,
    "Memberwise Permitted Qty": "N.A",
    "Minimum Haircut %": "VAR rate"
  } -- still getting the same error

Comment: Which error? The error message in your question was very specific about the location of the problem. Where does your real error message point to?

Comment: it's fixed now, i assigned the file to a variable and opened it using json.load instead of loads and it somehow worked, dont't know why